# How do i fix my output in my C program using format specifiers? the program is running but the output is not as expected

Tags: c, logic

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int age;
    char name;
    clrscr();
    printf("NAME: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("AGE: ");
    scanf("%i", &age);
    printf("\n\n\t\t Hi, %s ! You are %i years old."name, age);
    getch();
}
```

I'm having trouble with my output im expecting: Hi, Marvin! You are 16 years old. but the output is always like this: Hi, e error Abnormal program termination! You are 15 years old. The format specifier for name is not working but the age is working what should I do?

Comment: `char name` => `char name[100]`. and drop the `&` when scanning the name, And your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I doubt that your code compiles, since in printf() you missed ',' :

```
printf("\n\n\t\t Hi, %s ! You are %i years old.", name,age);
```

Second, change following:

```
  char name;
  clrscr();
  printf("NAME: ");
  scanf("%s",&name);
```

to

```
char name[100];
  clrscr();
  printf("NAME: ");
  scanf("%s",name);
```

Comment: char name[] => char name[XX] = {0};

Comment: You should also add width limit like `scanf("%99s, name)`. Using plain `%s` is as bad as using `gets`.

Comment: @code_seeker thanks sir! but im really confused what is the use of [100]? we haven't tackled that yet in our class.

Comment: To prevent potential buffer overflow, pass the maximum length to `scanf()`:  `scanf("%s",name);` -> `scanf("%99s",name);`

Comment: `char` is single character stored in one byte (8bits)(e.g `char name = 'a';`).In your code `char name;` expecting string of characters (e.g `char name ="David";` string is just a character array with the convention that the end of the valid data is marked by a null '\0'.). C assumes that it expecting single character, where you are passing string of characters, You have to tell C that you are expecting string of characters. Here `char name[100]`, telling the C that `name` is array and 100 is array size.